# How to capture post method while redirecting from third party website to front end localhost page?

Tags: angularjs, redirect, routes

**Hi all, I'm using Angular for front end and my route works perfectly in my local but when the third party website is redirecting to my localhost page i'm getting 404 error not found. And the third party website is redirecting to local host with a response in post method. How can i capture this page?**

[image]

**Please refer the above image that the response i get from third party website. Is there any other way that i can solve it?**